# iText7 Convert PDF to image while maintaining the highlighting

Tags: c#, itext7

I am using iText7(C#) and am looking for a way to convert a pdf page to image **leave the highlighting**. The goal is to create a rendered image (not searchable) of the pdf.

I have tried with this code but without success

```
using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(destinationFilename, new WriterProperties().SetPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_2_0)).SetSmartMode(true))
using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(sourceFilename))
using (PdfDocument pdfSource = new PdfDocument(pdfReader))
using (PdfDocument pdfDestination = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter))
using (Document document = new Document(pdfDestination))
{
    int pages = pdfSource.GetNumberOfPages();
    for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
    {
        PdfPage page = pdfSource.GetPage(i);

        PdfFormXObject pdfFormXObject = page.CopyAsFormXObject(pdfDestination);
        iText.Layout.Element.Image image = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(pdfFormXObject);
        document.Add(image);
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You are aware that an `iText.Layout.Element.Image` is not necessarily a _bitmap_ image? Thus, all your code does is copying the static content from one PDF to the next, dropping dynamic elements (annotations, attachments, ...). And now you want it to keep some dynamic elements. Perhaps you should explain more clearly what you want to achieve...

Comment: I want convert singole page of pdf in jpg or png keeping dynamic elements (annotations, attachments, ...).

Comment: *"I want convert singole page of pdf in jpg"* - an `iText.Layout.Element.Image` won't help you for that, see above. In the iText 7 context you may want to take a look at the [pdfRender iText 7 Core add-on](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/convert-pdf-to-image-pdfrender).

Comment: As @mkl mentioned iText pdRender has this functionality, it is and will however not be available in C# due to the rendering engine used. It is available in two versions; a Java version, and also a CLI (Command Line Interface) version which you can call from any language. You can give the [demo](https://itextpdf.com/en/demos/pdfrender) a try to see if it does what you need.

Answer (score -3):

https://staticrules.furnishedfinder.com/135c0c6c-37cd-4224-8850-72cc1e8d1a33.png

'itexsharp
Public Shared Function CreatePDF(ByVal baseuri As String, ByVal html As String, ByVal destination As String) As Integer
Try
Dim prop As ConverterProperties = New ConverterProperties()
prop.SetCharset(baseuri)
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, New FileStream(destination, FileMode.CreateNew), prop)

```
        Return 1
    Catch
        Return 0
    End Try
End Function
```

i am use this code pdf convert successfully but image is not convert and not showing on pdf but if i open browser then show image

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question - the OP wants to render a pdf page as a bitmap image (using a mechanism that is not suited for the task), not a HTML page with an image as a PDF page.